# How to manage and develop two slightly differents branches

Tags: git, production-environment, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I have some software in my git repo.

- "master" branch for actual unstable state
- "prod" for production ready
- And also I have branch "clientA" which is close to "prod" but have a lot
  of work-arounds about old libs/APIs

[image: example]

When I have finished featurebranch with the new functionality, I want to apply this for clientbranch and for prod branch.

[image: after]

Usually, I do this with cherry-pick, but in real life I have more than one clientBranch, and that is hard enough.

I am still sure, that it should be better way to manage this.

Please, point me to right direction.

Comment: Might be worth looking into rebasing? That allows you to apply changes that have already been made on one branch to another.

Comment: @orbrey No because rebase do not "duplicate" commits (except if you keep a ref on it --but that's, in this case equivalent to a cherry pick--)

Comment: It's unclear why a straight merge is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the good way to do it is to create your feature branch from the last commit common to your 2 branches `prod` and `clientBranch`.

Then, when you think that your feature branch is OK, then merge it into `prod` and `clientBranch`.

Hoping that code has not diverged too much from your common ancestor and that merge will be easy...

Like what is done with the green branch in [this workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) that is merged back into `master` and `development`.

> And also I have branch "clientA" which is close to "prod" but have a lot of work-arounds about old libs/APIs

But perhaps the best thing to do is rather `rebase` (or merge) your client branch onto `prod` to keep them in sync if in `clientBranch`, you only have these work arounds...